# Pandas Computing Groupby Stats based on Rows of Multiple Null Columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, statistics, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe as follows:

```
   df :

   ST   LW      UD  vl
   
   E1   e1   pp@yr   2
   F3   l1   pp@yr   4
   F3   l2   pp@yr   7
   E1   e3  pp2@yr   3
   F3   l4  pp3@yr  13
   E1   e5  pp3@yr   7
   F3   l6  pp3@yr   9
   E1   e7  pp2@yr   5
   E1   e8  pp3@yr   3
   F3   f9  pp4@yr   2
   F3  f11  pp4@yr   5
   F3  f13  pp5@yr   7
   F3  f7   pp5@yr   9
```

The task what I want to do is to take the mean and std based on column ST if only it contains E1 and do the following :

```
     dfD = df[df['ST'] == 'E1']

     stats_df = dfD.groupby('UD')['vl'].describe()[['mean', 'std']]


     mys = pd.DataFrame(stats_df).reset_index()
```

The dataframe mys looks like this:

```
     mys


      UD       mean   std

      pp2@yr    4.0   1.414214
      pp3@yr    5.0   2.828427
      pp@yr     2.0   NaN
```

Then I merge the data with the original dataframe as follows:

```
       mdf = pd.merge(df, mys, how='left', on='UD')
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows:

```
       mdf


     ST  LW  UD     vl  mean    std
     E1  e1  pp@yr   2  2.0     NaN
     F3  l1  pp@yr   4  2.0     NaN
     F3  l2  pp@yr   7  2.0     NaN
     E1  e3  pp2@yr  3  4.0    1.414214
     F3 l4   pp3@yr  13 5.0    2.828427
     E1 e5   pp3@yr  7  5.0    2.828427
     F3 l6   pp3@yr  9  5.0    2.828427
     E1 e7   pp2@yr  5  4.0    1.414214
     E1 e8   pp3@yr  3  5.0    2.828427
     F3 f9   pp4@yr  2  NaN    NaN
     F3 f11  pp4@yr  5  NaN    NaN
     F3 f13  pp5@yr  7  NaN    NaN
     F3 f7   pp5@yr  9  NaN    NaN
```

SORRY FOR TAKING THIS LONG. But now  I am coming the actual problem statement:

**The issue is that the last four rows**. The issue is that whenever mean and std are both Null, then I want to compute the mean and std based on only the rows which have both Null based on ST = F3 only and grouby based on the UD column. So the output should like (**Note: I computed the mean and stats for the last 4 rows**)

```
   finaldf


     ST  LW   UD     vl mean    std

     E1  e1  pp@yr   2  2.0     NaN
     F3  l1  pp@yr   4  2.0     NaN
     F3  l2  pp@yr   7  2.0     NaN
     E1  e3  pp2@yr  3  4.0    1.414214
     F3 l4   pp3@yr  13 5.0    2.828427
     E1 e5   pp3@yr  7  5.0    2.828427
     F3 l6   pp3@yr  9  5.0    2.828427
     E1 e7   pp2@yr  5  4.0    1.414214
     E1 e8   pp3@yr  3  5.0    2.828427
     F3 f9   pp4@yr  2  3.5    1.5
     F3 f11  pp4@yr  5  3.5    1.5
     F3 f13  pp5@yr  7  8.0    1.0
     F3 f7   pp5@yr  9  8.0    1.0
```

I can try to loop through the 'mdf' dataframe and find if both mean and std column have null values and then groupby based on those rows only but computationally thats not becoming efficient and I was looking for a efficient pythonic solution. Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if what you want is to filter out the rows that have null values on the dataframe and then calculate the mean and std of those rows, you could create a mask and use that mask to filter the df and calculate the values you wish to later insert them to the data frame. 

It will look something like this:

```py
mask = mdf[(mdf['mean'].isna()) & (mdf['std'].isna())]
mean = mask['v1'].mean()
std = mask['v1'].std()
mdf[(mdf['mean'].isna()) & (mdf['std'].isna())]['mean'] = mean
mdf[(mdf['mean'].isna()) & (mdf['std'].isna())]['std'] = std
```

**NOTE: You could continue to add restrictions to the mask by just typing &(and) |(or), followed by the condition in parenthesis, for example: & (mdf['ST']='F3')**

Comment: I did it a bit different way by separating the two sets ( one with null or without null) and then taking the stats based on non null and then merging the dataframes